# how to select rows with no null values (in any column) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

I have a table called `table1`

It has 100 columns: {`col1`, `col2`, ...,`col100`}

I understand how to `SELECT` rows *not* containing null values in a specific column for instance `col1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

> How do I `SELECT` **all** rows that do not contain null values *in any column*

### Attempt

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE * IS NOT NULL
```

but this returns an error in `MySQL` (which I am using)

Comment: `WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL AND .....`

Comment: You mean there should not be any single null in any of the column/row?

Comment: If you have 100 columns to check, you will write 100 x `and colx is not null`

Comment: 100 columns?!? Perhaps time to redesign the database.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri yes. I want to select rows with no nulls in any field

Comment: Yeah so as suggested by others, there is no straight way to achieve this. You must need to write 100 AND clauses.

Comment: If they are all numeric data type columns, you can save some typing: `WHERE col1 + col2 + ... + col100 IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: `WHERE CONCAT(col1, col2, ... , col100) IS NOT NULL` do the same for any scalar datatype. But separate checks are the most fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly list each column.  I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null and . . .
```

Some people might prefer a more concise (but slower) method such as:

```
where concat(col1, col2, col3, . . . ) is not null
```

This is not actually a simple way to express this, although you can construct the query using metadata table or a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

While I would recommend writing out each column name and refactoring your table as suggested, here's an option using `dynamic sql`:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ', 
              GROUP_CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' IS NOT NULL AND '), 
              ' IS NOT NULL') INTO @sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pixGicq6FzAxKWSDSsyuiL/0)

Answer (score 1):

To return rows with no nulls in any columns: (in PostgresSQL)

```
SELECT *  
FROM *tablename*  
WHERE *tablename*.* IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This wont work.

Comment: To VLQ Queue reviewers: [Wrong answers are not Very Low Quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality). Please vote "Looks OK".

Comment: See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=046743a6d6970a85ec036558a68412ff)

Comment: @Shmiel Thanks for spotting! This code works in Postgres SQL not mysql [db fiddle postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=046743a6d6970a85ec036558a68412ff)

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of each column and multiply them. If the result is not null then all columns are non null values. Try following sample code. Since I am not using multiple AND clause, it is a better approach.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (OdSal INT,NewSal INT,EmpName CHAR(20),IsCurrentEmp BIT)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES
(100,150,'Vikas',1),        -- No null records
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),      -- all records are null
(NULL,NULL,'Nayanthara',1), -- more than 1 column is null
(NULL,150,'Priyamani',1)    -- only one column is null

--Will return only one row
SELECT * FROM #Temp
WHERE LEN(OdSal) * LEN(NewSal) * LEN(EmpName) * LEN(IsCurrentEmp) IS NOT NULL
```

[image: Result of above code]