# How to find rows where every column has NULL value

Tags: sql, sqlite, statistics, data-analysis

I'm trying to filter out rows, which have NULL values in every column. Since there are around 30 columns, it seems unfeasible to type them out 1 by 1. Is there a way I can do this for the entire table?

I tried something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE column1 IS NULL AND column2 IS NULL -- etc...
```

However this is very time consuming, going through all the columns manually; how can I filter out rows, which have all column values as NULL?

Comment: You could execute a dynamically generated query.  You cannot do this in pure SQLite though.  If you are using the `sqlite3` command line you could use .once to write the generated statement to a file, then .import to execute it.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076546/how-to-select-rows-with-no-null-values-in-any-column-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

Maybe type a little and get the result you need:

```
-- step 1. get the column list of a table 
select group_concat(name) as column_list 
  from pragma_table_info('[table_name]');

-- step 2. select those ALL-NULL rows, [column_list] is from the above
select *
  from [table_name]
 where coalesce([column_list]) is null;
```

An example:

```
-- create a table 
create table t_null (
    c1  int,
    c2  int,
    c3  int);

insert into t_null
values 
(null, null, null),
(null, null, null),
(null, null, null);
```

```
-- get column list from metadata
select group_concat(name) as column_list 
  from pragma_table_info('t_null');

column_list|
-----------+
c1,c2,c3   |

-- 
select *
  from t_null
 where COALESCE(c1,c2,c3) is null;
```